# Share a photo to facebook via javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm using a very simple javascript to share an URL to facebook wall:

```
window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+something);
```

This allows user to finish the sharing in facebook confirmation window. However, now I need to share an image in a similar way.
I'm also using [open graph protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21297463/607407) to make facebook display preview of my site properly. But preview invoked by using proper facebook tags is useless:

[image]
<sup>I wonder: how can I force facebook to appear in english?</sup>

Is it possible to either share site as an image or share image by it's URL directly?

If possible, I wan't to do without Facebook API scripts on my site, as well as any iframes or other <del>ugly</del> external stuff.
I also have no interest in knowing what the user did with the share window.

Comment: You need to use open graph meta tags.

Comment: Do you mean `<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/preview.gif" />`? I'm using that. But that won't share a big image. The site shares mathematical equations and I need them to be readable on Facebook. Otherwise, I can just share url's.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the image meta tag in your page head. (add your image url to the facebook og:image meta tag and so on and so forth)

```
<!-- for Google -->
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />

<meta name="author" content="" />
<meta name="copyright" content="" />
<meta name="application-name" content="" />

<!-- for Facebook -->          
<meta property="og:title" content="" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:image" content="" />
<meta property="og:url" content="" />
<meta property="og:description" content="" />

<!-- for Twitter -->          
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="" />
```

Comment: Thanks for such a nice collection - that will surelly be useful to somebody, but not for me. I need the shared stuff to appear like a big, readable image. The purpose is sharing mathematical expressions directly to facebook so my fellow students can read them without going to the application.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using this one?

Add this after the body

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <!-- FB Like -->
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

and this to where your share button to appear

> < div class="fb-share-button" data-type="button_count">

Answer (score 0):

One way, that I can think of, is sharing an image in the form of a Facebook post. But again, it requires the use of [Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed/). Anyways, I'll just share this method here and you can use it in case you feel like using Facebook API.

For this you can make a POST request to the `/{user-id}/feed` endpoint. For example:

```
me/feed?message="Test"&link={Image_URL}&access_token={User_Access_Token}
```

This method requires a valid [User Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#usertokens) with publish_stream permission.